# Java, Swing, sql- Can I match a value entered in textfield with two column in the database

Tags: java, sql, swing

Can I match a value entered in textfield with two column in the database.

It is required in a application which has  options of "Save" and "search" according to the id but id is in combined form of String and Integer (eg abc/345) and the next id is incremented version of last id ie abc/346,abc/347 So I create two columns to store id in database , first for string part and second for integer part

problem is that When I enter full id ie abc/345 in textfield and click on the "Search button" then the other fields should be fill according to this full id

Comment: You could read the digits starting from the end until you get a non digit or the start of the String, then separate the String and the Integer/Long and send both to search the field in database.

Comment: which part of this are you having problems with?  what have you tried?  (Because the answer to your "can i match..." question is "yes", but we need more details to help you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a solution:
Use the `getText()` method of `Textfield` to get the id (string/int) and use a `StringTokenizer` to split the id in two parts: string and id.
Then you can easily query the database with these two requirements..

Code sample:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer ("abc/346", "/");
String id_string = st.nextToken();
String id_int = st.nextToken();
```

Comment: OP's question is about how to split the id in two part.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, you right, I made a mistake. `StringTokenizer` is to use, not `StringBuffer`

Comment: StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer ("abc/346", "/"); 
string id_string = st.nextToken();
String id_int = st.nextToken();